# GLSL: pow vs multiplication for integer exponent

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, exponent

Which is faster in GLSL:

```
pow(x, 3.0f);
```

or

```
x*x*x;
```

?

Does exponentiation performance depend on hardware vendor or exponent value?

Comment: This should truly depend on the hardware vendor and shader optimisation. But by doing 'x * x * x' manually you might override the compiler optimization

Comment: @codetiger That sounds reasonable, but do compilers recognize constant integer exponent? There is no `pow(float, int)` in GLSL, so if compilers do not handle this special case somehow, unrolling exponentiation by hand may be faster than floating-point exponentiation.

Comment: I accept the point you are putting forward, but it totally depends on your hardware and environment. So if you are building it for a specific hardware, then it is worth unrolling in your code otherwise not. I would also suggest optimising your code using the Open Source GLSL (https://github.com/aras-p/glsl-optimizer) to see what it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While this can definitely be hardware/vendor/compiler dependent, advanced mathematical functions like `pow()` tend to be considerably more expensive than basic operations.

The best approach is of course to try both, and benchmark. But if there is a simple replacement for an advanced mathematical functions, I don't think you can go very wrong by using it.

If you write `pow(x, 3.0)`, the best you can probably hope for is that the compiler will recognize the special case, and expand it. But why take the risk, if the replacement is just as short and easy to read? C/C++ compilers don't always replace `pow(x, 2.0)` by a simple multiplication, so I wouldn't necessarily count on all GLSL compilers to do that.

Comment: and for GLSL pow x must be always positive, otherwise it can trigger undefined behaviour / different behaviour on different GPUs, see https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/pow.xhtml . So when x can be negative, don't use pow (alone).

Answer (score 13):

I wrote a small benchmark, because I was interested in the results.
In my personal case, I was most interested in exponent = 5.

Benchmark code (running in Rem's Studio / LWJGL):

```kotlin
package me.anno.utils.bench

import me.anno.gpu.GFX
import me.anno.gpu.GFX.flat01
import me.anno.gpu.RenderState
import me.anno.gpu.RenderState.useFrame
import me.anno.gpu.framebuffer.Frame
import me.anno.gpu.framebuffer.Framebuffer
import me.anno.gpu.hidden.HiddenOpenGLContext
import me.anno.gpu.shader.Renderer
import me.anno.gpu.shader.Shader
import me.anno.utils.types.Floats.f2
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

fun main() {

    fun createShader(code: String) = Shader(
        "", null, "" +
                "attribute vec2 attr0;\n" +
                "void main(){\n" +
                "   gl_Position = vec4(attr0*2.0-1.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n" +
                "   uv = attr0;\n" +
                "}", "varying vec2 uv;\n", "" +
                "void main(){" +
                code +
                "}"
    )

    fun repeat(code: String, times: Int): String {
        return Array(times) { code }.joinToString("\n")
    }

    val size = 512

    val warmup = 50
    val benchmark = 1000

    HiddenOpenGLContext.setSize(size, size)
    HiddenOpenGLContext.createOpenGL()

    val buffer = Framebuffer("", size, size, 1, 1, true, Framebuffer.DepthBufferType.NONE)

    println("Power,Multiplications,GFlops-multiplication,GFlops-floats,GFlops-ints,GFlops-power,Speedup")

    useFrame(buffer, Renderer.colorRenderer) {

        RenderState.blendMode.use(me.anno.gpu.blending.BlendMode.ADD) {

            for (power in 2 until 100) {

                // to reduce the overhead of other stuff
                val repeats = 100
                val init = "float x1 = dot(uv, vec2(1.0)),x2,x4,x8,x16,x32,x64;\n"
                val end = "gl_FragColor = vec4(x1,x1,x1,x1);\n"
                val manualCode = StringBuilder()
                for (bit in 1 until 32) {
                    val p = 1.shl(bit)
                    val h = 1.shl(bit - 1)
                    if (power == p) {
                        manualCode.append("x1=x$h*x$h;")
                        break
                    } else if (power > p) {
                        manualCode.append("x$p=x$h*x$h;")
                    } else break
                }

                if (power.and(power - 1) != 0) {
                    // not a power of two, so the result isn't finished yet
                    manualCode.append("x1=")
                    var first = true
                    for (bit in 0 until 32) {
                        val p = 1.shl(bit)
                        if (power.and(p) != 0) {
                            if (!first) {
                                manualCode.append('*')
                            } else first = false
                            manualCode.append("x$p")
                        }
                    }
                    manualCode.append(";\n")
                }

                val multiplications = manualCode.count { it == '*' }

                // println("$power: $manualCode")

                val shaders = listOf(
                    // manually optimized
                    createShader(init + repeat(manualCode.toString(), repeats) + end),
                    // can be optimized
                    createShader(init + repeat("x1=pow(x1,$power.0);", repeats) + end),
                    // can be optimized, int as power
                    createShader(init + repeat("x1=pow(x1,$power);", repeats) + end),
                    // slightly different, so it can't be optimized
                    createShader(init + repeat("x1=pow(x1,${power}.01);", repeats) + end),
                )

                for (shader in shaders) {
                    shader.use()
                }

                val pixels = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4)

                Frame.bind()

                glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

                for (i in 0 until warmup) {
                    for (shader in shaders) {
                        shader.use()
                        flat01.draw(shader)
                    }
                }

                val flops = DoubleArray(shaders.size)
                val avg = 10 // for more stability between runs
                for (j in 0 until avg) {
                    for (index in shaders.indices) {
                        val shader = shaders[index]
                        GFX.check()
                        val t0 = System.nanoTime()
                        for (i in 0 until benchmark) {
                            shader.use()
                            flat01.draw(shader)
                        }
                        // synchronize
                        glReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels)
                        GFX.check()
                        val t1 = System.nanoTime()
                        // the first one may be an outlier
                        if (j > 0) flops[index] += multiplications * repeats.toDouble() * benchmark.toDouble() * size * size / (t1 - t0)
                        GFX.check()
                    }
                }

                for (i in flops.indices) {
                    flops[i] /= (avg - 1.0)
                }

                println(
                    "" +
                            "$power,$multiplications," +
                            "${flops[0].roundToInt()}," +
                            "${flops[1].roundToInt()}," +
                            "${flops[2].roundToInt()}," +
                            "${flops[3].roundToInt()}," +
                            (flops[0] / flops[3]).f2()
                )

            }
        }
    }


}
```

The sampler function is run 9x 512² pixels * 1000 times, and evaluates the function 100 times each.

I run this code on my RX 580, 8GB from Gigabyte, and collected the following results:

| Power | #Mult | GFlops* | GFlopsFp | GFlopsInt | GFlopsPow | Speedup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1246 | 1429 | 1447 | 324 | 3.84 |
| 3 | 2 | 2663 | 2692 | 2708 | 651 | 4.09 |
| 4 | 2 | 2682 | 2679 | 2698 | 650 | 4.12 |
| 5 | 3 | 2766 | 972 | 974 | 973 | 2.84 |
| 6 | 3 | 2785 | 978 | 974 | 976 | 2.85 |
| 7 | 4 | 2830 | 1295 | 1303 | 1299 | 2.18 |
| 8 | 3 | 2783 | 2792 | 2809 | 960 | 2.90 |
| 9 | 4 | 2836 | 1298 | 1301 | 1302 | 2.18 |
| 10 | 4 | 2833 | 1291 | 1302 | 1298 | 2.18 |
| 11 | 5 | 2858 | 1623 | 1629 | 1623 | 1.76 |
| 12 | 4 | 2824 | 1302 | 1295 | 1303 | 2.17 |
| 13 | 5 | 2866 | 1628 | 1624 | 1626 | 1.76 |
| 14 | 5 | 2869 | 1614 | 1623 | 1611 | 1.78 |
| 15 | 6 | 2886 | 1945 | 1943 | 1953 | 1.48 |
| 16 | 4 | 2821 | 1305 | 1300 | 1305 | 2.16 |
| 17 | 5 | 2868 | 1615 | 1625 | 1619 | 1.77 |
| 18 | 5 | 2858 | 1620 | 1625 | 1624 | 1.76 |
| 19 | 6 | 2890 | 1949 | 1946 | 1949 | 1.48 |
| 20 | 5 | 2871 | 1618 | 1627 | 1625 | 1.77 |
| 21 | 6 | 2879 | 1945 | 1947 | 1943 | 1.48 |
| 22 | 6 | 2886 | 1944 | 1949 | 1952 | 1.48 |
| 23 | 7 | 2901 | 2271 | 2269 | 2268 | 1.28 |
| 24 | 5 | 2872 | 1621 | 1628 | 1624 | 1.77 |
| 25 | 6 | 2886 | 1942 | 1943 | 1942 | 1.49 |
| 26 | 6 | 2880 | 1949 | 1949 | 1953 | 1.47 |
| 27 | 7 | 2891 | 2273 | 2263 | 2266 | 1.28 |
| 28 | 6 | 2883 | 1949 | 1946 | 1953 | 1.48 |
| 29 | 7 | 2910 | 2279 | 2281 | 2279 | 1.28 |
| 30 | 7 | 2899 | 2272 | 2276 | 2277 | 1.27 |
| 31 | 8 | 2906 | 2598 | 2595 | 2596 | 1.12 |
| 32 | 5 | 2872 | 1621 | 1625 | 1622 | 1.77 |
| 33 | 6 | 2901 | 1953 | 1942 | 1949 | 1.49 |
| 34 | 6 | 2895 | 1948 | 1939 | 1944 | 1.49 |
| 35 | 7 | 2895 | 2274 | 2266 | 2268 | 1.28 |
| 36 | 6 | 2881 | 1937 | 1944 | 1948 | 1.48 |
| 37 | 7 | 2894 | 2277 | 2270 | 2280 | 1.27 |
| 38 | 7 | 2902 | 2275 | 2264 | 2273 | 1.28 |
| 39 | 8 | 2910 | 2602 | 2594 | 2603 | 1.12 |
| 40 | 6 | 2877 | 1945 | 1947 | 1945 | 1.48 |
| 41 | 7 | 2892 | 2276 | 2277 | 2282 | 1.27 |
| 42 | 7 | 2887 | 2271 | 2272 | 2273 | 1.27 |
| 43 | 8 | 2912 | 2599 | 2606 | 2599 | 1.12 |
| 44 | 7 | 2910 | 2278 | 2284 | 2276 | 1.28 |
| 45 | 8 | 2920 | 2597 | 2601 | 2600 | 1.12 |
| 46 | 8 | 2920 | 2600 | 2601 | 2590 | 1.13 |
| 47 | 9 | 2925 | 2921 | 2926 | 2927 | 1.00 |
| 48 | 6 | 2885 | 1935 | 1955 | 1956 | 1.47 |
| 49 | 7 | 2901 | 2271 | 2279 | 2288 | 1.27 |
| 50 | 7 | 2904 | 2281 | 2276 | 2278 | 1.27 |
| 51 | 8 | 2919 | 2608 | 2594 | 2607 | 1.12 |
| 52 | 7 | 2902 | 2282 | 2270 | 2273 | 1.28 |
| 53 | 8 | 2903 | 2598 | 2602 | 2598 | 1.12 |
| 54 | 8 | 2918 | 2602 | 2602 | 2604 | 1.12 |
| 55 | 9 | 2932 | 2927 | 2924 | 2936 | 1.00 |
| 56 | 7 | 2907 | 2284 | 2282 | 2281 | 1.27 |
| 57 | 8 | 2920 | 2606 | 2604 | 2610 | 1.12 |
| 58 | 8 | 2913 | 2593 | 2597 | 2587 | 1.13 |
| 59 | 9 | 2925 | 2923 | 2924 | 2920 | 1.00 |
| 60 | 8 | 2930 | 2614 | 2606 | 2613 | 1.12 |
| 61 | 9 | 2932 | 2946 | 2946 | 2947 | 1.00 |
| 62 | 9 | 2926 | 2935 | 2937 | 2947 | 0.99 |
| 63 | 10 | 2958 | 3258 | 3192 | 3266 | 0.91 |
| 64 | 6 | 2902 | 1957 | 1956 | 1959 | 1.48 |
| 65 | 7 | 2903 | 2274 | 2267 | 2273 | 1.28 |
| 66 | 7 | 2909 | 2277 | 2276 | 2286 | 1.27 |
| 67 | 8 | 2908 | 2602 | 2606 | 2599 | 1.12 |
| 68 | 7 | 2894 | 2272 | 2279 | 2276 | 1.27 |
| 69 | 8 | 2923 | 2597 | 2606 | 2606 | 1.12 |
| 70 | 8 | 2910 | 2596 | 2599 | 2600 | 1.12 |
| 71 | 9 | 2926 | 2921 | 2927 | 2924 | 1.00 |
| 72 | 7 | 2909 | 2283 | 2273 | 2273 | 1.28 |
| 73 | 8 | 2909 | 2602 | 2602 | 2599 | 1.12 |
| 74 | 8 | 2914 | 2602 | 2602 | 2603 | 1.12 |
| 75 | 9 | 2924 | 2925 | 2927 | 2933 | 1.00 |
| 76 | 8 | 2904 | 2608 | 2602 | 2601 | 1.12 |
| 77 | 9 | 2911 | 2919 | 2917 | 2909 | 1.00 |
| 78 | 9 | 2927 | 2921 | 2917 | 2935 | 1.00 |
| 79 | 10 | 2929 | 3241 | 3246 | 3246 | 0.90 |
| 80 | 7 | 2903 | 2273 | 2276 | 2275 | 1.28 |
| 81 | 8 | 2916 | 2596 | 2592 | 2589 | 1.13 |
| 82 | 8 | 2913 | 2600 | 2597 | 2598 | 1.12 |
| 83 | 9 | 2925 | 2931 | 2926 | 2913 | 1.00 |
| 84 | 8 | 2917 | 2598 | 2606 | 2597 | 1.12 |
| 85 | 9 | 2920 | 2916 | 2918 | 2927 | 1.00 |
| 86 | 9 | 2942 | 2922 | 2944 | 2936 | 1.00 |
| 87 | 10 | 2961 | 3254 | 3259 | 3268 | 0.91 |
| 88 | 8 | 2934 | 2607 | 2608 | 2612 | 1.12 |
| 89 | 9 | 2918 | 2939 | 2931 | 2916 | 1.00 |
| 90 | 9 | 2927 | 2928 | 2920 | 2924 | 1.00 |
| 91 | 10 | 2940 | 3253 | 3252 | 3246 | 0.91 |
| 92 | 9 | 2924 | 2933 | 2926 | 2928 | 1.00 |
| 93 | 10 | 2940 | 3259 | 3237 | 3251 | 0.90 |
| 94 | 10 | 2928 | 3247 | 3247 | 3264 | 0.90 |
| 95 | 11 | 2933 | 3599 | 3593 | 3594 | 0.82 |
| 96 | 7 | 2883 | 2282 | 2268 | 2269 | 1.27 |
| 97 | 8 | 2911 | 2602 | 2595 | 2600 | 1.12 |
| 98 | 8 | 2896 | 2588 | 2591 | 2587 | 1.12 |
| 99 | 9 | 2924 | 2939 | 2936 | 2938 | 1.00 |

As you can see, a power() call takes exactly as long as 9 multiplication instructions. Therefore every manual rewriting of a power with less than 9 multiplications is faster.

Only the cases 2, 3, 4, and 8 are optimized by my driver. The optimization is independent of whether you use the .0 suffix for the exponent.

In the case of exponent = 2, my implementation seems to have lower performance than the driver. I am not sure, why.

The speedup is the manual implementation compared to pow(x,exponent+0.01), which cannot be optimized by the compiler.

Because the multiplications and the speedup align so perfectly, I created a graph to show the relationship. This relationship kind of shows that my benchmark is trustworthy :).

[image: Speedup vs Multiplications]

Operating System: Windows 10 Personal
GPU: RX 580 8GB from Gigabyte
Processor: Ryzen 5 2600
Memory: 16 GB DDR4 3200
GPU Driver: 21.6.1 from 17th June 2021
LWJGL: Version 3.2.3 build 13